# python-requests hanging when downloading a mass amount of files

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2, python-requests

I am trying to use python-request package to download a mass amount of files(like 10k+) from the web, each file size from several k to the largest as 100mb.

my script can run through fine for maybe 3000 files but suddenly it will hang.
I ctrl-c it and see it stuck at

```
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 327, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 493, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 319, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
```

Here is my python code to do the download

```
basedir = os.path.dirname(filepath)
if not os.path.exists(basedir):
    os.makedirs(basedir)
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
        if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
            f.flush()
```

I am not sure what went wrong, if anyone has a clue, please kindly share some insights.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [requests response.iter\_content() gets incomplete file ( 1024MB instead of 1.5GB )?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645212/requests-response-iter-content-gets-incomplete-file-1024mb-instead-of-1-5gb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a duplicate of the question that @alfasin linked in their comment. Judging by the (limited) traceback you posted, the request itself is hanging (the first line shows it was executing `r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)`).

What you should do is set a timeout and catch the exception that is raised when the request times out. Once you have the URL try it in a browser or with curl to ensure it responds properly, otherwise remove it from your list of URLs to request. If you find the misbehaving URL, please update your question with it.

Comment: actually I have tried this, I can download the file directly from firefox with no issue, that was why I posted this question on SO. But thanks for your response.

Comment: The fact is that the request is made but the server never responds so something external to requests is causing this to hang. `version, status, reason = self._read_status()` in the traceback indicates that we still haven't received anything from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation and it seems like a bug in the requests package was causing this issue. Upgrading to requests package 2.10.0 fixed it for me.

For your reference the change log for Requests 2.10.0 shows that the embedded urllib3 was updated to version 1.15.1  [Release history](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/)

And the release history for urllib3 ([Release history](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/urllib3) ) shows that version 1.15.1 included fixes for:

- Chunked transfer encoding when requesting with chunked=True. (Issue #790)
- Fixed AppEngine handling of transfer-encoding header and bug in Timeout defaults checking. (Issue #763)